# Pine Script Error " Syntax error at input ':='." in My Script

Tags: pine-script-v4

I am working on below pine script but it is giving me an error for line number 17.
Error is " Syntax error at input ':='"
I tried script by replacing ':=' with '=' but still error is showing.

I am not getting where I am wrong.

I admit that I am not an expert pine script codding just learnt from videos and other materials.

```
//@version=4
 study("Auto Anchored Volume Profile", overlay=true)

 // Define the input variables
 autoAnchor = input(true, "Auto Anchor")
 anchorPeriod = input(1, "Anchor Period") // Number of bars to anchor the profile
 profileWidth = input(10, "Profile Width") // Number of bars to include in the profile

 // Calculate the anchor point
 anchorPrice = na
 if autoAnchor
     anchorPrice := close[anchorPeriod]

 // Calculate the volume profile
 profile = array.new_float(profileWidth, na)
 for i = 0 to profileWidth - 1
     profile[i] := volume[i]

 // Plot the volume profile
 for i = 0 to profileWidth - 1
     if not na(profile[i])
         line.new(x1=anchorPrice, y1=i, x2=anchorPrice + profile[i], y2=i, color=color.blue,           
 width=1)

 // Plot the anchor point
 plotshape(autoAnchor, title="Anchor Point", location=location.absolute, color=color.red,      
 style=shape.labelup, text="A")

 // Plot the current price
 plotshape(close, title="Current Price", location=location.absolute, color=color.green,      
 style=shape.labeldown, text="C")
```

Comment: I tried same script by converting in version 5 but same error continue.
I tried to add INPUT command in below three lines also.

autoAnchor = input(true, "Auto Anchor")
anchorPeriod = input(1, "Anchor Period") // Number of bars to anchor the profile
profileWidth = input(10, "Profile Width") // Number of bars to include in the profile

Comment: Are you using chatGPT? Due to such poor accuracy Stackoverflow has [banned ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). TradingView has also decided [not to provide support](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/) for ChatGPT.

Comment: Yeah... it's obviously generated code... And there are MANY 1-question users with such codes here... However I will let my answer visible, but I will take more care from now on. THX for the hint

Comment: Could you be so glad and provide feedback to the answers? That's how Stackoverflow lives

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reassign a historical series value `profile[i] := volume[i]` and that's not possible.

You could use an array to hold the values you want to iterate. This creates an array of your values on each bar.

```
barsProfile = array.new_float()
for i = 0 to profileWidth - 1
    array.push(barsProfile, volume[i])
```

Now you can use those values on each bar:

```
for i = 0 to profileWidth - 1
    if na(array.get(barsProfile, i)
```

*Comment: A more sufficient way would be to hold those values in a `var array`...*

Comment: thanks for your valuable time to reply but it's not working so i have dropped this script. thanks again.